# Why hive is not able to store special characters like 'á' with MultiDelimitSerDe?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I want to load the french char like 'á', 'é' etc in hive with MultiDelimitSerDe but i am getting � char instead of french char.  I tried with 'serialization.encoding'='utf-8' and different codes but it is not working

Could anyone help me in handling these special characters in MultiDelimitSerDe.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried with LazySimpleSerDe ?